# Can I dynamicaly generate routes from MyBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml file in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, routes

As in the question above. How can I access all the route names from MyBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml file and stick them to the array. I want to use regular expresions to pull from an array only values with certain patern and use them to generate navigation menu. Any clues ?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use the `Router` instance. It has a method called `getRouteCollection` which returns, well, a `RouteCollection`. This object has all the information you need about every route your application makes.

```
$router = $this->get('router'); // The service name
$collection = $router->getRouteCollection(); // The routes
foreach ( $collection->all() as $name => $route ) { // a Route instance
    // Do your regular expression matching here
}
```

For further information you can look into the source at `Symfony\Component\Routing`.

If you want to create routes depending on other routes, I would replace and extend the `Router` class, then override the above method.